# 8 Queens Fitness Function

Tags: r, n-queens

I am trying to code the Fitness Function for 8 Queens in R from a method I found in C#. This is what I have in R so far:

```
getFitness <- function(QueenString) {
    Translation <- Translate(QueenString)
    Collisions <- 0
    for (i in 1:length(Translation)) { # Iterate through all bits in the gene
        x <- i
        y <- Translation[i] # grab the ith bit
        j <- i + 1
        while (j < length(Translation)) {
            if (abs(j-x) == abs(Translation[j]-y))
                Collisions <- Collisions + 1
            j <- j + 1
        }
        j <- 0
    }
    return(Collisions)
}
```

`QueenString` is a `bitstring` in the form of the following:

```
c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

The `Translate` function turns the above `bitString` into the following `bitstring`:

```
c(5, 2, 7, 7, 8, 2, 8)
```

So essentially, we're working with the above `Translate` string; not the `QueenString` for the `fitness` function. The C# code I am trying to adapt from is below:

```
public void CalcFitness()
{
    int collisions = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < genes.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            int x = i;
            int y = genes[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < genes.Length; j++)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(j - x) == Math.Abs(genes[j] - y))
                    collisions++;                        
            }
        }
}
```

With my code, I'll get 3 for the number of collisions; but this is much lower than the actual number of collisions. An example printout is shown below:

```
* * * * Q * * * 
* Q * * * * * * 
* * * * * * Q * 
* * * * * * Q * 
* * * * * * * Q 
* Q * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * Q 
* * * * * * Q *
```

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Maybe you are having problems with floating point precision when comparing numbers with `==`. Try doing: `if (abs(abs(j-x) - abs(Translation[j]-y)) < 1e-8)` instead.

Comment: If that solves it, then I have an even better suggestion: use integers everywhere. I can write an answer for it.

Comment: I think it's indexing problems translating C#'s 0-indexed to R's 1-indexed arrays. If `genes.Length` is 3, in C# `i` will be 0, 1, 2. When `i` in C# is the middle value, 1,  `j` will only take value 2.  For the corresponding case in R, `i` will be 1, 2, 3. When `i` in R is 2 (the middle value), you initialize `j` to `i+1`, which is 3, but as `length(Translation)` is 3 and you have a strict `<` in your `while` loop, the comparisons in the loop are not run. So I think you need to change `<` to `<=` in the `while` condition.

Comment: Sorry everyone; but the solutions given so far haven't been able to solve the problem. I appreciate everyone trying though. I am open to any more suggestions if you have them. Thanks.